# What was the tornado that swallowed up Lex Luthor and Superboy Prime?

Tags: dc, superman

In the Superman comics before the character change in 1986, has it ever been explained what that tornado was that swallowed up Lex Luthor and Superboy Prime?

I remember seeing that same tornado in one of the Crisis On Infinite Earths issues from 1985. Any help is really appreciated to clarify this for me.